# Restricting elements in showTimePicker

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, flutter, dart

What I'm trying to achieve: Showing the TimePicker selector where certain hours/minutes are disabled.

I know the show**Date**Picker has a `selectableDayPredicate` argument which can be used to achieve this, but I didn't find anything like it for the **showTimePicker** function.

If this isn't possible, is there any other Flutter widget where you can either (1) provide a list of hours and minutes to be displayed or (2) has a callback that checks each value if it can be displayed, similar to showDatePicker ?

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: There is an issue about that: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23717